# How do I edit default index values for x positions in matplotlib bar chart

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, dataframe

With the following code I am displaying a bar chart using matplotlib. I am trying to show the x labels for each column to be the values for the OS key. Instead it print the index positoins for each category. The OS key is the category and the Conn is the values for each category. How do I go about this. Been struggling with the documentation and trial and error. Thank you.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

raw_data = {
    'OS': 
    ['Android', 'Microsoft', 'Apple iPad', 'Apple iPhone', 'Apple Mac'], 
    'Conn': 
    [76, 88, 84, 67, 53]}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['OS', 'Conn'])

%matplotlib inline

myplot = df.plot(kind='bar')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another solution is [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) from column `OS`:

```
df.set_index('OS').plot(kind='bar')
```

[image: graph]

Answer (score 1):

pass [`x='OS'`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html) to use those values for the x-axis:

```
myplot = df.plot.bar(x='OS')
```

[image]